# Logitech G930 configuring media buttons for Spotify

Tags: spotify, wireless-headset, logitech-headset

I just bought the Logitech G930 wireless headset and I love it, its really great so far. I was just wondering if it is possible to assign the media buttons to Spotify? Right now the applications list is pretty limited.

Comment: I cant comment on the answer so Ill put it here. I cant seem to find anything that you are talking about. No plugins section or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Download [Spotify.dll](https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/G930-Spotify-Controller/tree/master/bin) and add it into the G930 G-key application list by using the plus under 'plugin'